# Create regex that contains certain values

Tags: regex

I need regex that contains and have mandatory at least one of each

Uppercase letters -- A, B, C...

Lowercase letters -- a, b, c...

Numbers -- 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9...

Special characters --  ` ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & *

like aaaaAAA123! or 0987ZZZZZz@

Comment: What have you tried?  Please read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  And you might want to consider some study here:  https://regex101.com/

Comment: Looks like on of those password validation regexes, I'm pretty sure you can find the basic concept (using lookaheads) on google and aply to your own set of rules.

Comment: @LukStorms no, of course it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site surely has similar questions to validate passwords.
But it's still amusing to craft a regex for a particlar case.

The regex below will match strings that contain all 4 character groups.

```regex
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[`~!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&*]+$
```

The 4 lookaheads garantee that at least 1 character for each character group is available.